# Redirect to google

Tags: javascript

I just want to redirect the user to google search when he type some thing in text box and then submit, for that i coded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gotosearch(){
var search = document.getElementById('q').value;
window.location = "http://www.google.com.pk/#hl=en&source=hp&biw=1024&bih=604&q="+search+"&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=1";
return true;
}
</script>
```

But window.location does not redirect to google page

but I failed...

Comment: Failed how? Does the method not do anything? Error message? Unable to retrieve the value of 'q'? Please be more specific.

Comment: Have you tried sticking some `alert()` s in to see how far it's getting? For example, one on function call, one after defining search, etc...

Comment: Actually it work if I again alert after window.location.href which is not a good practice....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to format the search string to be URL-compatible (e.g. replace `' '` with `'+'` and replace other reserved characters with `'%xx'` hex values)
- There needs to be a `?` in the URL before the parameter list.  The `#` character means to go to an anchor (i.e. `<a name="foo"></a>`) on the page.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com.pk/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=test

try that link

Comment: try

window.location.href = "http://www.google.com.pk/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=test"

Comment: Actually it work if I again alert after window.location.href which is not a good practice....

Comment: Window.location doesnt always work, use the whole "window.location.href", just making sure you are because your code up top didnt say that.